# Shortcut to reload frame in Firefox?

Tags: macos, mac, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a **keyboard shortcut** to reload a frame in Firefox? I'm on a Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, I assigned a mouse gesture to reload frame using FireGestures. Seems to me that it works fine. It is not a shortcut but it does the job ....

Comment: Faster than right clicking and manually choosing to reload the frame, no?

Answer (score 0):

You can press `Ctrl + R` key to refresh the Firefox.

If you want to reload a single iframe you can use `Menu + H + R` key to reload.

Comment: That will refresh the whole page.  He's asking how to reload a particular frame within a page.

Comment: As he said Menu + h + r works. Aka Press Shift + F10 to bring up the menu, then type h and r to reload the frame you are in. Its not the fastest way in the world but it is a shortcut...