# Does Chrome have a keyboard shortcut to reload an iframe?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, iframe

Is there a keyboard shortcut for Google Chrome that lets you reload a frame (iframe) that has focus? The only way I've found to do it is via right click.

Pressing <kbd>F-5</kbd> while the frame has focus (e.g. while actively in a form element) reloads the entire *parent* page or does nothing, depending on where the focus lies within the frame. I'm hoping to avoid that, as I'm debugging a rather massive form that is loaded in an iframe.

**Update:**

- Version: Chrome 16.0.912.75 (I love those version numbers) Anyway, stable.
- OS: Windows 7 and XP.

Comment: Is it possible to open the iframe content in a new tab?

Comment: Which operating system? I ask, because AutoHotkey is perfect for this kind of thing on Windows.

Comment: Are you able to use e.g. Safari instead? I solved it with Safari... but Chrome apparently has bugs related to reloading iframes.

Comment: I'm hoping for something cross-OS, however I'm using the stable version on XP and Windows 7 currently. I'll happily accept an answer that says 'no' with a link and summary of a bug report, I can't be the only one wondering about this :)

Comment: @DanielBeck Yes, but kind of hard to debug. The frame is (sometimes) loaded in a modal, but the behavior is the same either way. Shortly, opening in a new tab is not going to be possible.

Comment: I tried going the bookmarklet route. Works like a charm in Safari, but I'm pretty sure there's a bug in Chrome. Will have to investigate some more. Sorry couldn't be of more help.

Comment: @DanielBeck That was actually a lot of help. Thanks for chiming in. I fear the answer to this is 'no' :)

Comment: In case someone needs it: In Safari, you can use the bookmarklet `javascript:(function(){x=document.activeElement;if(x.tagName=="IFRAME"){x=x.contentWindow;x.location.reload();}})();`. I'm afraid a bug prevents this from working in Chrome though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. There's no shortcut because the browser needs to know what frame to reload. You can right-click inside the iFrame and select `Reload frame` from the context menu.

There's also a [suggestion to program a mouse gesture](https://superuser.com/questions/160406/shortcut-to-reload-frame-in-firefox) for this purpose but it's for Firefox. You can check out Chrome extensions for mouse gestures.

Comment: `document.activeElement` gives you the iframe from the parent document or a bookmarklet, if its content is focused.

Comment: Any suggestions for an extension that might suit the problem? They are, after all, a rather vast sea :)

Comment: So you're suggesting to create a bookmark containing JS that will work the following way: *user clicks inside an iFrame* -> *user clicks on the bookmark*. How's that different from *right-click the iFrame* -> *click Reload frame*?

Comment: @TimPost: There's no way to do it without a mouse and in fewer than 2 steps because of the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model). Even an extension needs to know what the active iFrame is.

Comment: @dnbrv Extensions can use local storage, which is why I asked. I don't mind telling an extension what ID I'm scoping if I can just tab through it later.

Comment: @dnbrv Opera has a keyboard shortcut (alt+f5), so it's not an impossible task.

Comment: Welcome five years later and people still get annoyed to death by this missing feature. No matter what I try, I cannot get Chrome to properly reload an iFrame. Even with the "Disable Cache" checkbox set in an open dev window, it still caches JS / CSS files.